# Python socket.accept nonblocking?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, nonblocking

Is there a way I can use python's socket.accept() in a non-blocking way that simply runs it and lets me just check if it got any new connections? I *really* don't want to use threading.
Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You probably want something like `select.select()` (see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#select.select)). You supply `select()` with three lists of sockets: sockets you want to monitor for readability, writability, and error states. The server socket will be readable when a new client is waiting.

The `select()` function will block until one of the socket states has changed. You can specify an optional fourth parameter, `timeout`, if you don't want to block forever.

Here is a dumb echo server example:

```
import select
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind(('', 8888))
server_socket.listen(5)
print "Listening on port 8888"

read_list = [server_socket]
while True:
    readable, writable, errored = select.select(read_list, [], [])
    for s in readable:
        if s is server_socket:
            client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
            read_list.append(client_socket)
            print "Connection from", address
        else:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            if data:
                s.send(data)
            else:
                s.close()
                read_list.remove(s)
```

Python also has `epoll`, `poll`, and `kqueue` implementations for platforms that support them. They are more efficient versions of `select`.

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke the `setblocking(0)` method on the Socket to make it non-blocking. Look into the [asyncore module](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html) or a framework like [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Comment: I tried that, and got the error that "A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately"

Comment: @pajm what else do you expect to happen if a non-blocking operation has nothing to do? By the way I wouldn't call that an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can make select non-blocking by setting the timeout parameter to 0. In that case select polls. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html