# Python client sockets connecting on the same server socket port

Tags: python, sockets, client, port

I am working for the first time on sockets with python.
I need to connect more than a client socket to the same server socket.

To do this I used the the following code:

```
import socket
import time
import random

from threading import Thread
import thread
import subprocess, signal, os

class ServerObject:
    def __init__(self, port):
        self.socket = ''
        self.host = ''
        self.port = port
        self.conn = ''
        self.data = ''

        print "Server port is: ", self.port

        def openSocketConnectionAsServer(self):
            self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
            self.socket.listen(5)
            self.conn, addr = self.socket.accept()
            print 'Server Connected by', addr

        def getData(self):
            return self.data

        def getHost(self):
            return self.host

        def getPort(self):
            return self.port

        def sendMessage(self, message):
            try :
                self.conn.sendall(message)
            except socket.error:
                print 'Server Send failed'
                sys.exit()

        def receiveMessageFromClient(self):
            while 1:
                reply = self.conn.recv(4096)
                if not self.data: break
                return reply

        def receiveMessageFromServer(self):
            reply = self.socket.recv(4096)
            return reply

        def closeConnectionAsServer(self):
            self.socket.shutdown(1)
            self.socket.close()
            del self.socket

class ClientObject:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = str(random.choice('abcdefghil'))
        print "Client Data Random: ", self.data
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.port = ''

    def openSocketConnectionAsClient(self):
        self.port = 50000 + random.randint(1,3)
        print "Client socket port is: ", self.port
        try:
            self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except socket.error:
            print 'Client Failed to create socket'
            sys.exit()

        print 'Client Socket Created'

        try:
            remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( self.host )
        except socket.gaierror:
            print 'Client Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting'
            sys.exit()

        self.socket.connect((remote_ip , self.port))

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getHost(self):
        return self.host

    def getPort(self):
        return self.port

    def sendMessage(self, message):
        try :
            self.socket.sendall(message)
        except socket.error:
            print 'Client Send failed'
            os.sys.exit()

    def receiveMessageFromServer(self):
        reply = self.socket.recv(4096)
        return reply

    def closeConnection(self):
        self.socket.shutdown(1)
        self.socket.close()
        del self.socket

def clientProcess():
    print "Client Start the client process"
    client1 = ClientObject()
    for i in range(1,10): 
        try:
            print "Client try to open the connection socket: attempt number ",i
            client1.openSocketConnectionAsClient()
            print "Client connection socket established on port ", client1.getPort()
            break
        except socket.error:
            print "Client connection error on the port ", client1.getPort()
            if i == 10:
            os.sys.exit()

    print "Client send the message"
    client1.sendMessage(client1.getData())
    print "Client receive the message back"
    client1.receiveMessageFromServer()
    print "Client Data requested: ", client1.getData(), " Hostname: ", client1.getHost(), " Port: ", client1.getPort()
    print "Client Close connection"
    client1.closeConnection()

def serverProcess(port=40007):
    print "Server oject create"
    server = ServerObject(port)
    print "Server open connection as server"
    server.openSocketConnectionAsServer()
    print "Server receive the client message"
    receivedMessage = server.receiveMessageFromClient()
    message = "Server Data requested are: "+receivedMessage
    print "Server send the message back to the client"
    server.sendMessage(message)
    print "Server close the connection with the client"
    server.closeConnectionAsServer()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    threadServer = Thread(target=serverProcess, args=[50001])
    print "New Server thread created with name: ", threadServer.getName()
    threadServer.start()

    for i in range(1,3):
        threadClient = Thread(target=clientProcess)
        print "New Client thread created with name: ", threadClient.getName()
        threadClient.start()
        threadClient.join()
```

When I run it, the first client is able to connect to the server, the second one never get connected, even though I close the connection (from server and client side) at the end of the first client thread.

Please, could anybody tell me, what's wrong in my code?

Thanks

Comment: You need to create a new process or thread for each new client. This can by done inside the Python code, or outside using xinetd or similar tools.

Answer (score 0):

What @Ber said was correct but incomplete.

You're problem is here:

```
self.socket.listen(5)
self.conn, addr = self.socket.accept()
```

`listen` will open up the port and prepare to receive connections. `accept` will **wait** for the next connection.

While you only need to call `listen` once, you must call `accept` multiple times, once per connection. There are several ways you can arrange this. For starters you could call `accept` again when the current connection closes, but this will only allow one client at a time. Better to have one thread call `accept` to wait for the next connection, but have it start a worker thread to handle each one.

Or you could use [non-blocking I/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308080/python-socket-accept-nonblocking/5308168#5308168), but if you go this way, check out [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Comment: More importantly - `accept` blocks until a client connects and then returns the ephemeral socket that is used to read+write to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I would **highly** recommend using the excellent [`socketserver`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#module-socketserver) module for doing stuff like this.  As for your code, the problem is that your *threaded* socket server only runs in a single thread.  At the very least, you should create a new thread to handle the connection after `accept`ing the new connection in `openSocketConnectionAsServer`.