# Program getting stuck at accept statement

Tags: python, class, sockets, raspberry-pi, serversocket

I've just posted a part of my program. The first time I run the program I could give the input from a client and the server crosses the accept, but when the program runs for second loop it gets stuck in the `mysocket.accept`. Making the socket non-blocking doesn't solve this.Does anyone know how to clear this error?

```
class Memory(threading.Thread):

    def __init__ (self):
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)

    def run(self):
        global data_queue
        while True:
            sleep(0.1)
            mysock.listen(5)
            print "waiting for data"
            conn, addr = mysock.accept()
            print "received data from client"
            data = conn.recv(1000)
            data_queue.put(data)

class Execute(threading.Thread):

    def __init__ (self):
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)

    def run(self):
        global data_queue
        while True:

            if not data_queue.empty():
                data = data_queue.get()
                if not data:
                    break
                if data == b'on':
                    print "on"
                    gpio.output(4,True)
                if data == b'off':
                    print "off"
                    gpio.output(4,False)
```

Client Program:

```
try:
    a = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error:
    print("Failed to create socket")
    sys.exit()

a.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1236))

while True:
    print "1.ON 2.OFF"
    choice = input('Enter your choice')
    if choice == 1:
        try:
            a.sendall(b"on")
        except socket.error:
            print("Failed to send")
            sys.exit()

    if choice == 2:
        try:
            a.sendall(b"off")
        except socket.error:
            print("Failed to send")
            sys.exit()

ms.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python socket.accept nonblocking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308080/python-socket-accept-nonblocking)

Comment: Do you know what socket.accept() is doing?

Comment: yeah , i know the basic function of socket.accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want in your Memory thread is this:

```
def __init__ (self):
    threading.Thread.__init__ (self)

def run(self):
    global data_queue
    mysock.listen(5)
    print "waiting for data"
    while True:
        sleep(0.1)
        conn, addr = mysock.accept()
        print "received connection from client"
        self.talk_to_client(conn)

def talk_to_client(self, conn):
    data = conn.recv(1000)
    while data != 'quit':
        reply = prepare_reply_to_client(data)
        data_queue.put(reply)
    conn.close()     # if we're done with this connection
```

Notice how I've moved the listen up above the while loop so it only happens once. Your problem is that your second call to listen() conflicts with the first. You should only call listen once. Subsequent accepts will clone the listen socket and use it for a connection. You then close that connection when your done with it, but your listen continues waiting for new connections.

Here's the canonical example in the python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example

Updated: Add example of extended interaction with client by writing method talk_to_client(conn)

Comment: the problem still persists :(

Comment: Do you know that it's getting input from a second client? If there is not a second client, the server will pend at the accept() until the next connection is requested.

Comment: no, while my program executes only a single client is present which gives command. I'll post my client progam.

Comment: @Shriram: This should be enough to at least remove one error in your code. You should post a new question using that but with a **real** [mcve], and either reference this one or just delete it. It this does not fix your problem, you have another one in unshown code...

Comment: @Shriram, if you only have one client, only one connection will be accepted. The server won't pass the second accept until it gets another connection. That's what accept() is for -- it sits there and waits for the next connection. Your program is behaving the way it's supposed to.

Comment: @TomBarron. Then is there a way to keep connected to a single client and send the commands 'on' and 'off' from the client to the server?

Comment: Yes, you just use the connection that accept returns you. You make send and recv calls on that connection, not accept more connection requests. I've updated the example code in my answer to show how this might work.

Comment: @TomBarron It shows an error.The error is as follows "talk_to_client() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: @Shriram, Oops, my mistake. talk_to_client() needs 'self' as its first argument. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @TomBarron prepare_reply_to_client function isn't defined? . I removed that function and gave the data directly to queue and set data = 'quit' inside the while loop. Another thing is that i moved the socket initialisation into the while loop in my client program. Thanks a lot Tom for the assistance . I'll edit ur answer and replace the function.

Comment: @Shriram I didn't define prepare_reply_to_client() because I don't know anything about your data. I intended it as a placeholder for you to define. Adding code inside the while loop to handle it is fine too. I'm glad I was able to help.