# How to control Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins from separate PC

Tags: python, c++, windows, ssh, raspberry-pi3

In my application I want to turn on certain GPIO pins that are on the Raspberry Pi from my PC's C++ script. My PC is currently running on Windows 10 and my Raspberry Pi on Raspbian.

The general idea I had was to write python scripts on the Raspberry Pi itself and run them somehow from my PC when needed. Although, I am not sure how to do this or if it's possible in C++. I know I can ssh into my Raspberry Pi and run scripts manually but the idea of this application is automation. I am able to connect my PC to the Raspberry Pi either by Ethernet or USB cables.

I have seen USB to GPIO modules that would probably work better although for now I am stuck with my Raspberry Pi.

Any knowledge or resources on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe be what you need is a client and server program to control your GPIO pins. Check out my client and server programs and dont forget to read the answer and its comments and make the change accordingly for the program to work.(My progams motives is to control an LED through the client and server programs , similar to controlling the GPIO pins )

[Program getting stuck at accept statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531893/program-getting-stuck-at-accept-statement)

PS: I hope you are having some knowledge about Threading and sockets.

Comment: I actually found a really useful library that enables me to ssh into the Pi and from there I am able to run the python scripts needed! Here is the link to the library. [link](https://www.libssh.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This answer will be pretty broad so feel free to leave a comment with questions.

The first things that are needed, are the python scripts on the Pi which control the GPIOs in however fashion we like. From then on we are able to execute these commands via ssh from almost any device. Although, we want this process to be automated. In other words, the user doesn't have to enter credentials to ssh into the Pi but rather have the program automatically do so.

Luckily, this library allows us to do so. -> https://www.libssh.org/

There is nice documentation as to how to create ssh sessions and executing the commands that we want. So I won't go into much detail. Although I will comment on one procedure that the documentation recommends but gave me a problem.

When authenticating the user via password we use method ssh_userauth_password(ssh_session session, const char* username, const char* password). The documentation suggests setting the second parameter to NULL. Which was what was giving me the problem.

Simply change this to the login name you use when you normally ssh into the Raspberry Pi. For most the default name is "pi".

```
ssh_userauth_password(my_ssh_session, "pi", password);
```